# How do I create an arbitrary number of instances of the same dependency chart in Helm 3?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

My application requires us to be running multiple instances of a database, let's say InfluxDB.
The chart we are writing should allow us to run an arbitrary number of databases, based on the values passed to the chart, so I can't `alias` a fixed number of times the `influxdb` chart in the `Chart.yaml` file.

The way I want to solve this challenge, is by having my main chart `main` have a range of values that specify the configuration. A quick example of `values.yaml`

```
databases:
 - type: influxdb
   name: influx1
   port: 9001
 - type: influxdb
   name: influx2
   port: 9002
```

I can iterate over this array with `range` easily, but I'm unsure of how to "call" the dependency chart from the `main.yaml` file. Arborescence:

```
main_chart
├── charts
│   └── influxdb-1.2.3.tgz
├── Chart.yaml
├── templates
│   └── main.yaml
└── values.yaml
```

I tried using `{{- include "influxdb" .Values.some_test_config}}`, but I get a `No template influxdb associated with template gotpl` error.

I also went through the Helm docs, but didn't find an answer.

Thanks for following through ! Any thoughts ?

Comment: Did you ever resolved this? I'm facing a similar challenge.

Answer (score 6):

You want to use helm chart dependencies with aliases:

https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#alias-field-in-dependencies

Update your Chart.yaml to include:

```
dependencies:
  - name: influxdb
    repository: https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com
    version: 1.2.3
    alias: influx1
  - name: influxdb
    repository: https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com
    version: 1.2.3
    alias: influx2
```

Then values.yaml would look like this:

```
influx1:
   port: 9001
   <other chart values>
influx2:
   port: 9002
   <other chart values>
```

Comment: How would you create a variable list of dependencies? Like if I have the list of ports in a variable that contains [9000,9001] and I want to loop over this list with a range to create one dependency per item. I get a syntax error if I try that