# Loop over Helm subcharts or a set of manifests

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helmfile

I want to have a parent chart that generates multiple copies of a subchart. For example, the values.yaml for my parent chart would be :

```
clients:
- one
- two
- three
```

When I deploy, I want it to create `subchart-release-one`, `subchart-release-two`, etc.
Can I do this using native Helm or do I have to use something like Helmfile?
I can go and add loops through all my manifests but this seems improper and tedious.

Having a parent chart allows me to keep track of the clients instead of deploying them separately.

Comment: Someone asked a similar question but didn't get a correct answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60770559/how-do-i-create-an-arbitrary-number-of-instances-of-the-same-dependency-chart-in

Comment: The answer in that question is not ok for you? You want the number of times a sub-chart is installed to be dynamic from the values? Because the easiest way is to list all the possible sub-chart releases as dependencies (but it's a static way to decide how many times and with which names a sub-chart is installed)